# IE9 bug: image 'load' event fires in dev, but not in prod

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-9, onload-event

We have an image upload dialog that allows a user to change their profile photo via AJAX. It works like this:

1) User clicks on "update photo" action.

2) Dialog opens

3) Current profile image is loaded, and 'load' event fires cropper initialization

4) User clicks "upload new photo"

5) Through multipart upload, response sends back success message with new photo's cdn link.

6) New photo URL replaces 'src' of image in dialog (the one that formerly held the user's original profile image).

6) New photo loads, fires 'load' event and initializes cropper.

In our dev environment, this works fine, but in production, that second 'load' (the one that happens after the new photo event never fires, thus stopping short of the initialization of the cropper. I'm using Charles to reroute our javascript requests to my local machine so dev and prod are using literally the exact same code to execute. The only difference is the environments (as far as I'm aware).

To be clear: The upload is a success in both cases, and returns a valid URL that confirms linked to the image that was just uploaded. The only issue, as far as I can see, is that new image in prod never fires the 'load' event. I've also not been able to produce this error in any browser but IE9.

Ideas?

Examples:

```
// How the image load event is bound
$image.on('load', handleImageLoad);

// How the image is being set (src is provided on upload-success):
$image.attr('src', src);

// handleImageLoad is called after image upload in dev, but not in prod
```

Test:

To test out the `imageEl.complete` theory, I set up this code:

```
  interval = setInterval(function () {
    if ($image[0].complete) {
      handleImageLoad();
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 0);
```

`handleImageLoad` is still never reached.

Comment: Not sure how we are supposed to be able to help you with nothing more than a vague description, but IE has some issues with the onload event, usually solved by using the `myImage.complete` property to check if the image is cached and trigger the onload event, and by always setting the source of the element after the onload event handler has been attached.

Comment: We can't help if you don't post the code

Comment: added some examples. They likely won't help you, as they're pretty straightforward.